# ¿Cómo pasar argumentos del registro de windows a un ejecutable en c#?

Tags: c#

Hola estoy creando una pequeña herramienta para un colega, la cual permite formatear dispositivos USB. Me pregunto de que forma puedo pasar un parámetro desde el registro de windows a dicha aplicación.
Lo que estoy buscando es que cuando mi amigo de click derecho sobre la unidad USB y le aparesca el menú contextual de windows y este seleccione mi herramienta esta se abra con la ruta de la unidad.

Comment: Es complicado. Si te gustan los desafíos, aquí tienes unos links que te podrían ayudar https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders

Comment: **Gracias man**, estuve revisando la `documentación` y veo que no es tan difícil.

Comment: De nada. Si logras tu cometido, podrías responderte a ti mismo y así ayudas a los que intenten lo mismo que tú.